# How to show diferent total on cart shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, cart

I am showing different `prices` on the `cart` based on the `quantity` of an `item`, if the `item` in the `cart` has more than `6` in the `item.quantity` it should count the `price` saved in a `metafield`, else it shown the `default price`. knowing this i want to show the `total` on the `cart` based on those `prices`, for example

```
//i declare a variable for the subtotal
{% assign subtotal = 0 &}
{% item.quantity >= 6 %}
    //if the item qty is greater than 6 i show a different prices, in this case a price saved on a metafield
    {% subtotal += item.product.metafields.global.wholesale_price | times:item.quantity %}
{% else %}
    {% subtotal+= item.price | times:item.quantity %}
{% endif %}
```

and finally show the subtotal

```
{{ 'general.cart_info.sub_total' | t }}<span><span class="amount">{{ subtotal | money }}</span></span>
```

as i have seen doing `subtotal += value` is not supported or i am using it wrong, is there a way to do this?

**Edited**

i did a workaround using hidden inputs and a js function like this

```
//on the liquid file i added the hidden field with a custom class with the sub-total of that row
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% item.quantity >= 6 %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ price | times: item.quantity }}" class="subtotals">
    {% else %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ sca_price }}" class="subtotals">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
//in the function i calculate de sum of all the rows and show the result on a div called show_subtotal
function calculateSubtotal()
{   
    var subtotal = parseInt(0);
    $('.subtotals').each(function(index, el) {
        subtotal += parseInt($(el).val());
    });
    subtotal = '$'+subtotal;
    subtotal = subtotal.slice(0,-2)+'.'+subtotal.slice(-2)
    $('.show_subtotal').html(subtotal);
}
```

this work but it is not the best way to do it, i should be able to do that on server side. any advice?

Comment: How do you plan to pass this adjusted value to checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just use `assign` again

```
{% assign subtotal = 0 &}
{% item.quantity >= 6 %}
    //if the item qty is greater than 6 i show a different prices, in this case a price saved on a metafield
    {% assign subtotal = item.product.metafields.global.wholesale_price | times: item.quantity %}
{% else %}
    {% assign subtotal =  item.price | times: item.quantity %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{{ item.final_line_price | money }}
```